# Is there any simple way to crawl all of the SharePoint 2010 site information to save it into a database?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, web-parts

I'm working with Visual Studio 2010 and Sharepoint 2010. I would like to know if there's a way to have a web part that crawls all the data within a SharePoint site so I can save it into a custom db.

Comment: You know it already _is_ in a database, right?

Comment: Why do you need it? It IS in the database already.

Comment: Yes well, let's say I just need a couple of info from each item, as the ID and Title let's say, to perform a couple of operations with another database of mine. The bottom line is, I do need to store some fields of certain info in a new db, despite of their existance on SharePoint's db.

Comment: What kind of info are you needing to store elsewhere, and why?  It would be easier to answer this question if we knew a little about what it is you are trying to acheive.  Its strongly discouraged to mess with the sharepoint DB (manually, or through code) directly.  There may be another way to acheive what you are looking to do.

Comment: Well, I don't want to mess with SharePoint DB, I just need to get data from all lists within a site. I does not matter why I need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found this article - [Document Library Tree View Web Part for SharePoint](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/sharepoint/librarytreewebpart.aspx) - it is a Web Part that shows all the info of any of the document libraries within a site. At least I know how to crawl that kind of library.

Comment: did you need to crawl the whole site, or just the lists?

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly create a custom web part that will do this. I do not know of an out of the box web part that will work. I began writing something like this when I found [SharePoint List Source and Destination](http://sqlsrvintegrationsrv.codeplex.com/releases/view/17652). It's a CodePlex project for an SSIS SharePoint adapter. We did not need a user interface for the extract, so we used it successfully last year for transferring data between SQL Server and SharePoint.

Comment: Extracting and Loading SharePoint Data in SQL Server Integration Services: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd365137.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like all you need to do is use the API, OOB web services, or the Client OM to write some code and access the lists directly. Which approach you take depends mostly on where the code will run.

Comment: Well I found this: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/sharepoint/librarytreewebpart.aspx, which is a webpart that shows all the info of any of the document libraries within a site. At least I know how to crawl that kind of library.